# El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy enviando datos de una vista a un controlador con `formData` pero cuando pasan al controlador me da un error que dice:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. El valor no puede ser nulo.
> Nombre del parámetro: String Descripción: Excepción no controlada al
> ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila
> para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el
> código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.ArgumentNullException: El valor no
> puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: String
>
> Error de código fuente:

```
Línea 157:        {
Línea 158:
Línea 159:            int Id = int.Parse(formCollection["Id"]);
Línea 160:            string Text = formCollection["Text"];
Línea 161:            int Contacto = int.Parse(formCollection["ContactoId"]);
```

En la linea del `Id` donde ya verifique los datos que si me llegan tal cual como los pongo.

```
public ActionResult Print(FormCollection formCollection)
        {

            int Id = int.Parse(formCollection["Id"]);
            string Text = formCollection["Text"];
            int Contacto = int.Parse(formCollection["ContactoId"]);
            string ContactoDos = formCollection["ContactoDos"];
```

Esta es el controlador donde los recibo.

Y así es como los envío.

```
function enviarInfo() {

        $('#frmPdf').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        var URL = '@Url.Action("Print", "ComoDatoDetalles")';

        var formData = new FormData($('#frmPdf')[0]);

        //var Id = $('#frmPdf input[name=Id]').val();
        //var Text = $('#frmPdf textarea[name=Dictamen]').val();
        //var Contacto = $('#frmPdf select[name=ContactoId]').val();

        var Id = document.getElementById("Id").value;
        var Text = document.getElementById("TextDictamen").value; /*$('#TextDictamen').val();*/
        var Contacto = document.getElementById("ContactoId").value;
        var ContactoDos = document.getElementById("ContactoDos").value;

        console.log('text -> ' + Text);
        console.log('contacto -> ' + Contacto);

        formData.append("id", Id);
        formData.append("Text", Text);
        formData.append("Contacto", Contacto);
        formData.append("ContactoDos", ContactoDos);


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ModalComoDato').modal('hide');

                Swal.fire('success', 'success', 'success').then(function () {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                });
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);

                var errorData = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                var errorMessages = [];
                for (var key in errorData) {
                    errorMessages.push(errorData[key]);
                }
                Swal.fire('Agregar Elemento', errorMessages.join("\n"), 'error');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Cambiar los `int` por los `string` ?

Comment: Tienes `int Contacto = int.Parse(formCollection["ContactoId"]);` y debería ser `int Contacto = int.Parse(formCollection["Contacto"]);`

Comment: Ya lo había puesto así pero el error me dice en el Id

Comment: Así debe ser, porque pones `formData.append("Contacto", Contacto);` Es decir el name es `Contacto` no `ContactoId`,  el otro error será por otra cosa

Comment: En tu controlador, ¿tienes más invocaciones de `Parse` o algún otro método que reciba información desde el cliente?

Comment: El dato que pasas es ```id``` no ```Id```.

Comment: @HéctorM. No, son las únicas 2 variables con las que uso el `Parse`

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich ya lo había corregido y ni así

Comment: Y dices que en la linea del id te arroja el error y que has verificado que llegan los datos en formCollection? como has verificado que efectivamente llegan los datos?

Comment: Mejor utiliza:
```var formData= $("#frmPdf").serialize();``` 
y  al ajax le pones ```DataType: 'json'```

Comment: Sí le pongo eso, en la variable de la función que tengo `formColecction`, no me recoge los datos